# Create Editor permission level on SharePoint

Tags: permissions

I'm creating a permission level on SharePoint called "Editor" to allow users to do the following only:

- Edit publishing pages: add/remove text, pictures, etc., in a page layout. Can't delete page. Can insert list views. Can't create a new page.
- Edit lists: add/remove/edit items in existing lists. Can't delete lists. Can't create a list.
- Site columns/content types: can't create these.
- New sites: can't create new sites.
- Site settings: can't access these.

Here's what I've checked on the "Add a Permission Level" page (basing it somewhat on Contributor role); is this correct for the Editor role that I need based on above requirements? All the items not appearing were left unchecked. Thanks for your help :)

List Permissions

- [X] Add Items  -  Add items to lists and add documents to document libraries.
- [X] Edit Items  -  Edit items in lists, edit documents in document libraries, and customize Web Part Pages in document libraries.
- [X] Delete Items  -  Delete items from a list and documents from a document library.
- [X] View Items  -  View items in lists and documents in document libraries.
- [X] Create Alerts  -  Create alerts.
- [X] View Application Pages  -  View forms, views, and application pages. Enumerate lists.

Site Permissions

- [X] View Pages  -  View pages in a Web site.
  document, or list item.
- [X] Browse User Information  -  View information about users of the Web site.
- [X] Open  -  Allows users to open a Web site, list, or folder in order to access items inside that container.
- [X] Edit Personal User Information  -  Allows a user to change his or her own user information, such as adding a picture.

Personal Permissions

- [no items checked here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you will have problems with `Can't delete page.` and `Can't create a new page` because of:

> [X] Add Items - Add items to lists and add documents to document
>   libraries.
>
> [X] Delete Items - Delete items from a list and documents
>   from a document library.

Since you have different behaviour for different lists eg. user can add 'basic' list item but not 'page' item you will need to create 2 Permissions Levels and then apply those to different list.

Simple example:

- Level 1 : Add, Edit and Delete Items
- Level 2 : Edit Items

You apply Level 2 to your Pages library and use Level 1 for other libraries.

Comment: A follow-up: For users to be able to insert list views into pages, do they need to have this permission as well? `[ ] Add/Remove Personal Web Parts  -  Add or remove personal Web Parts on a Web Part Page.` This is under Personal Permissions. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this can help: [Allow visitors to add or remove web parts in SharePoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866988/allow-visitors-to-add-or-remove-web-parts-in-sharepoint)